# How do I reference to the same instance of a class across multiple viewcontrollers?

Tags: swift, macos, delegates, protocols, viewcontroller

Or in other words... How do I delegate actions from one instance of a class, to three different View Controllers? At this time of writing I'm initiating a class as a public variable, making possible for all my viewcontrollers to access it to set itself as the delegate. But I don't like this approach, because it's limiting me to one instance of the class.

**My goal is to create an instance of a class, which is able to delegate certain things to three View Controllers - without making it it public. The reason I want to use classes is because I would like to be able to initiate more instances of the samme class, but I can't do that if it's a hardcoded public variable outside a View Controller class.**

I will try to explain this problem as well as I can. And thanks in advance!

1) I have three View Controllers, and a single Split View Controller:

Here's screenshot:

[image: storyboard]

2) I have a class called "ConnectionHandler". The purpose of that class is to connect to a WebSocket, maintain the connection and do certain stuff upon receiving specific packets. The ConnectionHandler class also inherits from another class, "PacketHandler".

3) Both ConnectionHandler and PacketHandler needs to delegate certain things to three different View Controllers: the main view controller, another view controller which contains a NSTextView, and lastly a View Controller which contains a NSTableView.

I will provide some of my code, and I will start with my ConnectionHandler:

```
import Starscream

class ConnectionHandler: PacketHandler, WebSocketDelegate {

    let ws = WebSocket(url: URL(string: "ws://localhost:8080")!)

    func connect() {
        ws.delegate = self
        ws.connect()
    }

    func disconnect() {
        ws.delegate = nil
        ws.disconnect()
    }

    func websocketDidReceiveMessage(socket: WebSocket, text: String) {
    }

    func websocketDidConnect(socket: WebSocket) {
    }

    func websocketDidDisconnect(socket: WebSocket, error: NSError?) {
    }

    func websocketDidReceiveData(socket: WebSocket, data: Data) {
    }
}
```

And the important bits from my PacketHandler:

```
class PacketHandler {

    var textViewDelegate: TextViewAppendDelegate?

    func message(packet: String) {
        // A message is detected, so I want to push this to a TextView
        textViewDelegate?.appendTextView(str: packet)        

    }    
}
```

The protocol:

```
protocol TextViewAppendDelegate {

    func appendTextView(str: String)

}
```

And the View Controller, which ConnectionHandler/PacketHandler delegates an action to:

```
class TextViewController: NSViewController, TextViewAppendDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var textView: NSTextView!

    func appendTextView(str: String) {
        // Code to append a message to a NSTextView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        socket.textView = self 
    }
}
```

As I've stated, I'm just initiating the ConnctionHandler class as a public variable, because that's the only way I know how to delegate to more than one View Controller. **If I initiate the class in the main View Controller, I find myself unable to to delegate to other View Controllers.**

I have thought about linking all three View Controllers to the same View Controller class, but I'm not sure about that one either. I have also thought about initiating the ConnectionHandler from one of the three View Controllers, and then (somehow) create delegates between the View Controllers, making it possible for other View Controllers to set itself as the delegate of certain aspects of the class. **I guess my mentality is that "View Controllers" needs to know about (or access) a instance of a "class" to be able to "set it self" as the delegate. Is there some other, better way?**

And again, thank you so much.

**Update:**
Jacobs answer can work if would like to use a Singleton. So I gave him the right answer. But after some more digging I learned about NotficationCenter, which suited my needs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is a singleton class.

The Apple Docs define this as:

> A singleton class returns the same instance no matter how many times an        application requests it.

You would implement this as:

```
 class ConnectionHandler {
     static let sharedInstance = ConnectionHandler()
     ...the rest of your code
}
```

Then in all of your View Controller's you access the sharedInstance.

Comment: Hi Jacob, thanks for the fast response!
So, if I were to initiate the class in my main View Controller like this:
`var socket = ConnectionHandler()`
I would just have to reference it in in other controllers like this:
`var socket = ConnectionHandler.sharedInstance`
And it would be the same instance? That's great, man! Thank you so much.

Comment: You wouldnt even have to do that. Simply say ConnectionHandler.sharedInstance anywhere you need it.

Comment: But I wonder... Let's say I would like to create a tabbed application, where each tab has it's own instance of these three View Controllers. Would each tab also access the same shared instance?

Comment: Yes it would. Take a look at the AVAudioSession in the documentation. It works on the same principle.